# How long do 'War Justifications' last in Victoria 2?

Tags: victoria-2

Several times I've gone to the diplomacy screen to start a war only to find my previous justifications are gone. Is there a time limit to 'claim' those justifications? If so, is there a way to make the game show a message or warning when it's about to happen? And if not, why did my justifications disappear?

Answer (score 1):

[The wiki](http://www.victoria2wiki.com/Casus_belli) describes the available Casus Belli. They usually only last half a year, sometimes one year. So, you have to be quick.

The game should provide you with an alert about soon to expire xasus belii. Possible you deactivated this alert, but as this question is really old, I doubt we can find out, why it's missing.